# Checking for XPath version

Tags: java, xml

How do I check if the XPath version I am using in JAVA is 1.0 or 2.0? I found that I am using jdk 1.6.0_20

Comment: I do understand that you probably meant "how to find out the XPath version from _within_ Java". Feel free to accept another answer if there is one.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description

It's version 1.0

Comment: Btw, found that by googling for `java 6 xpath`.